# how i change css with same element id for multiple element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple div on same id,
and i want change that all div backgorund.

```
function myfun(id) {
$('#pinsss').css({ background: "#0066ff"} );
}
```

this script working well to first element and others not working.

Comment: Use class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**note : keep in mind, id is unique. one element can have one id and it should be different from others. instead of id, if you can use class. because , class can use for any number of elements.**

```css
#one{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:50px;
  border:4px solid orange;
  }

#two{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:50px;
  border:8px solid red;
  }


#three{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:50px;
  border:6px solid blue;
  }


.all{
  background-color:pink;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  
  <div class="all" id="one"></div>
  <div class="all" id="two"></div>
  <div class="all" id="three"></div>
  

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

like above code, each div has `unique`  `id`.but same `class`, if you do any changes to the `class`, that will affect to all, which has same class, name.
but `id` is different, styles apply only for the declared `id`.

Answer (score 2):

IDs should be unique and only one element on a page should have a given ID.  Trying using a class instead.

Comment: thank you for answer.but there are have more element class with css.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should not use same id for all element, id should be unique to be ever element,

you should use class in this scenario, because you want to share the same behaviour for multiple element you can achieve this by using class,

Comment: thank you....i got answer.i changed css for id and changed class for script.its working.... :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different Id's for each element.

```
function myfun(firstId) {
$('#pinsss').css({ background: "#0066ff"} );
}

function myfun(secondId) {
$('#pinsss').css({ background: "#0066ff"} );
}
```